# URLConnection opening weirdness

Tags: java, http, url, httpurlconnection

Having a tough time understanding URLConnection and where connect() is possibly being called implicitly.

This code doesn't work:

```
URL url = new URL(firstUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.getHeaderField("Location"); //returns null
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

This code works:

```
URL url = new URL(firstUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
conn.getHeaderField("Location"); //returns the redirect URL
```

I'm having a tough time understanding this. Is the "getHeaderField" implicitly calling connect? I don't see that noted in the documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It actually does connect, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29
It should be mentioned in the docs, I agree...

Comment: Ahh, so the "getInputStream" opens the connect?

Comment: @cjcamisa anything that needs (part of) the server response implicitly does `.connect`. That includes `getContent`/`getInputStream`/`getErrorStream` for the body and `getHeaderField`/`getContentType`/etc for the header. See the *parent* class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html at the top of the page and under `connect()`